# App Engine Deploy Error 500 on Existing Project, Not on new project

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app deployed on Google App Engine that I suddenly receive a 500 Error when attempting to deploy a new version. I'm using the Google App Engine Launcher and receive the output shown below. I've tried multiple remedies after searching answers. I reinstalled Google App Engine Launcher and Python, checked for quota issues, but everything seems fine.

I finally tried creating a new project and I can deploy the same code to the new project, but not to my old project. I really don't want to have to move to a new project just to update my existing app. Any ideas why the same code will not deploy to my existing project?

```
10:20 AM Compilation starting.<br>
10:20 AM Compilation completed.<br>
10:20 AM Starting deployment.<br>
10:20 AM Rolling back the update.<br>
Error 500:<br>
--- begin server output ---<br>
Server Error<br>
A server error has occurred.<br>
--- end server output ---<br>
2018-05-09 10:20:45 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since around May 9th (the day that you posted your question), the **goapp deploy**  does not show compilation errors (it says "Compilation completed") and if there is a compilation problem it will only show this "Error 500", I also stumbled on this problem. Even **appcfg.py update -v** (verbose) does not show if there is a compilation error since that day.
In order to see the compilation errors, the solution that I found consists in using the **goapp serve** command (local deployment on your PC), which is a good practice anyway before doing a production deployment.
What's strange about your issue is that you said that you were able to deploy the same code on another project, so there should be no compilation error, but it's worth giving it a try in case you did not upload exactly the same code.